# Where's the foolish part ? Prove that 0/0 = 2

Tags: fake-proofs

I've been across this on the web:

\begin{align}
\frac{0}{0} & = \frac{100-100}{100-100} \\
& = \frac{10^2-10^2}{10(10-10)} \\
& = \frac{(10-10)(10+10)}{(10)(10-10)} \\
& = \frac{(10+10)}{10} \\
& = \frac{2}{1} \\
& = 2
\end{align}

---

Of course this is *wrong* but I can't tell where exactly since there is no obvious (to me at least) atrocity... Is this in the first line $ \frac{0}{0} = \frac{100-100}{100-100}$ ?

Comment: It's cancelling $10-10$ (dividing above and below the line with $0$).

Comment: By the way, you could just as well say $0/0=1$ (cancelling directly) or $0/0=(0\cdot 62389)/(0\cdot 32)=62389/32$. You are just masking the obvious mistake of division by zero, by calling your zero something else.

Comment: It's also the very first expression: 0/0 doesn't mean anything, so you can't manipulate it.

Comment: This is the "proof" why $0/0$ is *undefined* : if you rewrite it as $(100-100)/(50-50)$ wou will get $4$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to rewrite this proof by dividing by all powers of ten and what not.

The proof essentially goes:

$$ \frac{0}{0}=\frac{2\cdot 0}{1\cdot 0}=\frac{2}{1}$$

The problem is in the first line, when you write $\frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined. Of course you could define it, but then it would be equal to every fraction since
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$
if $ad=bc$, and if $a=b=0$, then this is always true, since for any $c$ and $d$, $0\cdot d=0\cdot c$.

But then all fractions are equal to each other, so there is only really one fraction: $\frac{0}{0}$. This seems a lot less useful than the system we had before.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide any number by $0$! In abstract algebra there are constructed algebraic structures where things similar to "dividing by zero" can be performed (zero divisors).

A new branch of mathematics is the **nonstandard analysis** in which with numbers which are tending to $0$ can be performed any calculations (these are infinitesimal numbers; it is in the set of hyperreal numbers).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove the factor
$$
\frac {10-10}{10-10}
$$

and assume that the rest is $0/0$.